# nftable rules get invalidated on reconnect (VDSL, ppp0)

Tags: debian, point-to-point-protocol, pppoe, nftables, reconnect

I'm rebuilding my router using nftables on debian jessie. I have a working setup up to the moment where my ISP decides to reassign a new WAN IP by reconnecting my DSL-link. After such a reconnect the router itself has an online connection, but masquerading doesn't work any more.

nftable setup before reconnect:

```
# nft list table nat
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            oif ppp0 masquerade
    }
}
```

nftable setup after reconnect:

```
# nft list table nat
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            oif 8 masquerade
    }
}
```

So I assume the downtime of ppp0 during the reconnect causes the related rules to be some kind of *unassigned*. Manually re-applying the nft rules (flush + add) solves this problem until the next reconnect.

How can I ensure the temporarily disabled rules will be automatically reassigned to ppp0 after the connection has been re-established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve this issue.

```
# nft list table nat
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        oifname "ppp0" masquerade
    }
}
```

You just have to use `iifname/oifname "ppp0"` instead of `oif/iif ppp0`. The latter addresses the interface by string rather than using the interface id. The quotes are optional, but I think it emphasizes the different interpretation well.

The manpage simply states:

> Type ifname: Interface  name  (16  byte string).  **Does not have to exist.**

I don't know if there's any downside like performance impacts when matching, but it feels like it's the correct solution.